# nginx-rtmp module on nginx test case

Tags: linux, nginx

I am trying to stream a video using nginx-rtmp with rtmp protocol.which i setup on my vm(started headless). I created a index.html and embedded on it JWPlayer with the rtmp url. On my localhost,

> how can I play the video from the browser
>   and is my configuration all right ?
>   I can't able to browse the video from my real machine

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>VoD Example</title>
        <script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/s7iNvOAyEeSMdQ4AfQhyIQ.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='videotest'></div>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        jwplayer('videotest').setup({
        file: 'rtmp://192.168.x.xxx/vod/bird.mp4',
        width: '50%',
        aspectratio: '16:9'
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my nginx.conf

```
 #user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  0.0.0.0;

        # rtmp stat
        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }
        location /stat.xsl {
            # you can move stat.xsl to a different location
            root /var/www/;
        }

        # rtmp control
        location /control {
            rtmp_control all;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}

rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
    notify_method get;
    chunk_size 8192;

        application vod {
        allow play all;
        wait_video on;
            play /var/www/html/video;
        push rtmp://192.168.x.xxx/vod/;
        }
    }
}
```

> I kept a videos  /var/www/html/video/bird.mp4

access.log

```
192.168.x.xx - - [15/Sep/2018:12:25:21 +0530] "GET /stat.xsl HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://192.168.x.xxx:8080/stat" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/69.0.3497.81 Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36"
```

error.log

```
2018/09/15 12:24:49 [notice] 23499#0: nginx/1.15.1
2018/09/15 12:24:49 [notice] 23499#0: built by gcc 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 
2018/09/15 12:24:49 [notice] 23499#0: OS: Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64
2018/09/15 12:24:49 [notice] 23499#0: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:1048576
2018/09/15 12:24:49 [notice] 23500#0: start worker processes
2018/09/15 12:24:49 [notice] 23500#0: start worker process 23501
2018/09/15 12:25:45 [info] 23501#0: *2 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.x.xx, server: 0.0.0.0:8080
2018/09/15 12:26:15 [info] 23501#0: *3 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 192.168.x.xx, server: 0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: May be this article can help - https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/11/streaming-video-demand-nginx-rtmp-module/

Comment: thank u so much, its working file